# Custom UIHint attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to create a custom version of the `UIHint` attribute?

When my company first adopted MVC, we used a lot of `Html.*` helper methods. We are in the process of redesigning out MVC template to make use of the full power of MVC. One way we are doing this is with Display and Editor Templates.

However, one popular HTML extension method we had was to generate dropdowns for Enums. One of the options we had was to sort by the int value or the description or text of the EnumMember.

I would like to see about creating a `EnumDropdown` attribute that accepts several parameters that can customize the output of the HTML dropdown. However, I don't think it's possible to do this while still retaining the benefits of the `UIHint` attribute. Meaning, that I won't be able to simply call `@Html.EditorFor(m => Model)`

I had found that there is a `System.Web.UI.IAutoFieldGenerator` interface but it doesn't appear to do what I want. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The newer versions of MVC have this built in now:

[EnumDropDownListFor HTML Helper](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/mvc51-release-notes#Enum)

The only thing UIHint does is suggest a Display or Editor template name. MVC will then add this name to the search path when looking for that template.

You can just use UIHint as is and have your generator create these for you in the correct folders and not have to customize it.

Comment: Yes, but then I loose the ability to be able to call `@Html.EditorFor(m => Model)` from my view. I then have to specific code for that property or create an EditorTemplate from the class.